# Android SharedPreference specific storage and retreival

Tags: android, storage, preferences

I am creating `SharePreference` using:

```
sharedPreference=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFE_LOCATION, 0);
preferenceEditor=mSharedPreference.edit();
preferenceEditor.commit();
```

And have setup a screen using `Preference From Code` SDK sample.

Now what I want is when user changes the preference using the code generated `PreferenceScreen` the changes should reflect in preference file `SHARED_PREFE_LOCATION` (from my code variable.) and not in `defaultSharedPreference`.

How can I do that.

**EDIT**

I know I can implement on `PreferenceChangeListener` and reflect the changes in the desired file. But thats tedious. Is there any straight forward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PreferenceManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) to set the preference name. This will make your preferences be stored in the location you specify. I recommend doing this before you add any preferences to your preference activity, this way any default values won't be saved to the default location:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(SHARED_PREFE_LOCATION);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```